# What is the best web based FTP file manager script?

Tags: ftp

It should have

- simple and clean design
- can log in with real FTP user accounts created in cPanel
- Installable on different SUB-Domain but must be about to point to ROOT folder on other sub-domain
- Open Source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used for a while a service called [Net2Ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/). Works like a charm, except that if you use their hosted tool, the size of the files that you can move is not too big. You can [download the script](http://www.net2ftp.com/homepage/download.html) (it's in PHP) and install it on your own domain.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Net2FTP is way out of date. Monsta FTP is free and regularly updated. www.monstaftp.com (disclaimer: I'm involved with this project)

Answer (score 2):

You can use file manager on your own server
download script from there

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/extplorer/files/
```

and you can look file manager form there

```
http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/
```

its simple PHP script and you can mamage all the main features form there such as: - add file, edit file, delete file, upload file, rename file, extract and many more features...